# stop a php from executing when clicked on cancel button

Tags: javascript, php

I want a php to stop executing when the user click on a cancel button.
Here my javascript code:

```
ui.showDialog('CARunning_DB');
var xhr = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new activeXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
data.append("string" , ketcher.getSmiles());
data.append("file" , AUserDir+"inputfile");
data.append("dir" , AUserDir);
data.append("mail",mail);
var thresh=document.getElementById("threshold").value;
data.append("threshold",thresh);
xhr.open( 'post', 'PHP/write_and_exec_opt.php', false );
xhr.send(data);
xhr.abort();
```

In the Dialog box 'CARunning_DB' there is a cancel button, I would like it to stop the php 'PHP/write_and_exec_opt.php'. Is it possible? How can I do this?

Thanks

PS: I am not using jquery